# How to check if a character in a string equals "w"

Tags: c++

I am failing to compare characters of a string in my program, I made a simpler version to showcase the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
        string s = "Hello world!";

        for(int i = 0; i<s.size(); i++) {
                if(s[i] == "w") {
                        cout << "This is a w!" << endl;
                }
        }
}
```

It returns this error:

> so.cpp:10:25: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
> 10 |                 if(s[i] == "w")

Comment: Single character literals use single quotes (`'w'`).

Comment: If you're used to Python, that is a slightly peculiar language in that it doesn't distinguish between characters and strings – in Python, `"a"[0][0][0]` is valid and equivalent to `"a"`. Most languages do make this distinction, and C++ distinguishes between `'a'` and `"a"` (and`"a"[0] == 'a'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"w"` is a pointer to the C string `['w', '\0']` in memory. You want to use single quotes instead so you are only comparing the character literal.

```c
 if (s[i] == 'w') {
     cout << "This is a w!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strings` accessed as arrays will return a char, which you can compare to using single quotes on your `w`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "Hello world!";

    for(int i = 0; i<s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'w') {
            cout << "This is a w!" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```